# SQLAlchemy Cascading Delete on Many to Many relations

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a cascade delete on my database with SQLAlchemy. I've got the tables (with unrelated fields removed):

```
action_permissions_to_groups = db.Table('action_permissions_to_groups', 
    db.Column('group_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id',  ondelete='cascade')),
    db.Column('action_permission_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('action_permission.id',  ondelete='cascade'))
)

class Group(db.Model, MyModel):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    action_permissions = db.relationship('ActionPermission', secondary=action_permissions_to_groups, cascade='delete')


class ActionPermission(db.Model, MyModel):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

In English, multiple `Groups` have multiple `ActionPermissions`. When I delete a `Group`, I want everything in the `action_permissions_to_groups` table to be deleted of all rows where the `group_id`matches the group being deleted.

The above code is giving me the following error when I try and delete a group:

> InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: DELETE statement on table 'action_permissions_to_groups' expected to delete 11 row(s); Only 12 were matched.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!